# Hiding View Node in Notion Sidebar

Tags: notion

I have a question about the Notion Sidebar display when I am combining Page with inline Views.  I'm trying to create a hierarchical Sidebar node using Page+Links in Notion.  I manage to create what I intend to have but with some quirky displays in Notion Sidebar.

Attached below is my KBDB (Database) in Notion that has different views based on some Titles.  Is there a way I can hide the node `View of KBDB` whenever I expand a node in the sidebar that has an inline link view to KBDB?

Or if there is a better way to implement the sidebar hierarchy than what I'm trying to do?

[image]